# Highchart Treemap with Multiple series and should behave live heat map

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a single TreeMap with multiple series for which I have created [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/r8tp8ct3/)

**Series : 1 look like below**

For every point a color has been defined. But in my case it would be difficult to define no of Colors.

**The dataset for below treemap is a below**

```
var _Dataset1

  = [{
  name: 'A',
  value: 6,
  color: '#80FF00'
}, {
  name: 'B',
  value: 6,
  color: '#ADFF30'
}, {
  name: 'C',
  value: 4,
  color: '#00FF7F'
}, {
  name: 'D',
  value: 3,
    color: '#90EE90'
}, {
  name: 'E',
  value: 2,
    color: '#8EBC8E'
}, {
  name: 'F',
  value: 2,
 color: '#3CB371'
}, {
  name: 'G',
  value: 1,
color: '#2E8A57'
}];
```

[image]

Series 2 : Look like below, it works purely works with the color no assigned t the datapoint.

[image]

The dataset for the above is as follows.

```
var _Dataset2

  = [{
  name: 'mango',
  value: 6,
  color:1
}, {
  name: 'Mango1',
  value:36,
  colorValue: 22
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  value: 4,
  colorValue: 3
}, {
  name: 'Pomgranate',
  value: 3,
  colorValue: 4
}, {
  name: 'Guava',
  value: 2,
  colorValue: 5
}]
```

The style for the above to series (Treemap)should look the below on.
The fiddle for the same is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/48ng9xjh/10/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`colorValue` property can be used only when **color axis** (included in **heatmap module**) is defined for the chart. Color axis is rendered in place of the legend and it's not possible to use the legend anymore.

I'd suggest to use `color` property for the points of your second series.

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.data.colorValue

---

### **Edit:**

After I checked this issue more carefully I noticed that `colorAxis.showInLegend` causes that series legend items don't show up.

I reported it and proposed a **workarond** here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8140

Comment: But it would be difficult to provide color for every datapoint. Can we not just replace the ColorAxis that renderd in the place of the legend with Series in legend place.?

Comment: but the result is being displayed for both the series now together. Also I require Treemap, sorry if my image looked like HeatMap instead.

Comment: This issue concerns **color axis** module - it works the same in heatmap and treemap. **Treemap demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y9jb077g/

Comment: Perfect, I will have the changes done accordingly in my application and make it working, if still I face issue I will get back to you for assistance.